# K means clustering in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to do k means clustering in scikit learn. Code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 10)
x = df.values
kmeans.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1))
```

If the parameter `n_init = random`, it chooses random initial centroids. Is there a way to fetch the initial centroids used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get your cluster centers after fitting the `KMeans` object to your data.

**Little trick !**

So what you can do is set the parameter `max_iter` to `1`. By default it is set to `300` and then centers may change at each iteration.

If you use **only one iteration** the algorithm will assign each sample to an initial center and then it will stop, not updating the centers.

Thus calling `.cluster_centers_` will give back the initial centroids !

Comment: I just one more question, if the max_iter = 300, after the center changes at ecah iteration, calling '.cluster_centers_ ' will give the latest centroid right ( the centroid at 300th iteration)?

Comment: @vikky you got it ;)

Comment: `km = KMeans(init=cluster_centers, n_init=1, max_iter=1)
print(km.cluster_centers_)` still getting same error

Comment: You need to fit your data first

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I assume you can try `centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_` before calling `fit()`

Comment: this will fetch me the initial centroids used by the library?

Comment: AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_' is what I am getting

Comment: I apologize, the `cluster_centers_` won't be available after calling `fit()`. I would create a centroids array and use it to create the cluster.  `kmeans = KMeans(init=centroids_array)`. This way we can customize the way centroids are initialized. Sorry again for not verifying my answer.